# Assign MOK passwords when Secure Boot from UEFI secure boot enabled after it was initially disabled

Tags: dual-boot, secure-boot

I have Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10 on dual boot. I initially installed Ubuntu with Secure Boot disabled in the UEFI.

I have been using it like this for a bit of time and now decided that I would like to set Secure Boot in UEFI to enabled. The only things I have installed in Ubuntu are nvidea and Docker.

How do I assign MOK keys for nvidea and Docker (not sure if it requires one) after I enable Secure Boot in UEFI? For example, do I have to uninstall nvidea with `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*` and then re-install to get the prompt to assign an MOK key?

I think my answer might be at the bottom of this article [UEFI/SecureBoot/DKMS link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot/DKMS) but I'm not really sure what they mean or the instructions.

FYI: I never disabled MOK using this command `sudo mokutil --disable-validation` because secure boot was already disabled in UEFI

Comment: The easiest way is to keep the useless Secure Boot disabled.